# CLion and remote headers

Tags: remote-access, clion

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to do something seemingly trivial. I'd like to install a few libraries to use in my project in a docker container (think of it as any other VM) but use the IDE from within the host to actually develop against it.

The direct dependencies somewhat work in that case, but their common counterparts like boost, etc are missing the headers in the IDE, so even though the program compiles, I get a bunch of errors and missing headers in the IDE.

Here is an example CMake file to use nghttp2 as a dependency in the project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(deptest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

################ hidapi

set(NGHTTP2_ROOT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/vendor/nghttp2)
set(NGHTTP2_LIB_DIR ${NGHTTP2_ROOT}/bin/lib)
set(NGHTTP2_INCLUDE_DIR ${NGHTTP2_ROOT}/bin/include)

include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(nghttp2_dep
                    PREFIX ${NGHTTP2_ROOT}
                    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2.git"
                    GIT_TAG "0641d314a62fc2f9ede5cbb487895236da4ae4f4"
                    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
                    PATCH_COMMAND ""
                    BINARY_DIR ${NGHTTP2_ROOT}/src/nghttp2
                    SOURCE_DIR ${NGHTTP2_ROOT}/src/nghttp2
                    INSTALL_DIR ${NGHTTP2_ROOT}/bin
                    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ./configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR> --enable-asio-lib
                    BUILD_COMMAND make
                    BUILD_BYPRODUCTS ${HIDAPI_LIB_DIR}/libnghttp2.a)

# hidapi requires an initial execution of "./bootstrap" to run autoreconf
ExternalProject_Add_Step(nghttp2_dep
                         bootstrap
                         COMMAND autoreconf -i && automake && autoconf
                         DEPENDEES download
                         DEPENDERS configure
                         WORKING_DIRECTORY ${NGHTTP2_ROOT}/src/nghttp2)

add_library(nghttp2 STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(nghttp2 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${HIDAPI_LIB_DIR}/libnghttp2.a)
add_dependencies(nghttp2 nghttp2_external)

################ test app

include_directories(build/vendor/nghttp2/bin/include)
#include_directories("build/vendor/std")

add_executable(deptest src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(deptest nghttp2)
target_link_libraries(deptest ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Any recommendations on how to achieve that? Since the dependencies are Linux only, I cant build and run everything on the mac directly, so I only want to use it as an IDE source but do all the compilation on the VM box, the only issues seems to be how to get CMake to understand where the headers are on the Mac. Also I'm using the latest CLion release.

Comment: I don't know whether this can be done using CLion, but it is not something CMake can help, it must be configured within CLion.

Answer (score 10):

**Reload your CMake project and then do the following:**

**Tools -> Resync with Remote Hosts**

Afterwards wait some seconds and don't be unpatient - the headers will be found after CLion completed indexing the new files, which may take some time in larger projects.

Since everything worked fine after the inital creation of the project, it seems the resync has to be done manually from time to time because CLion is becoming async for some reason.

Comment: Thank you! My CLion could not find the `#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>` after I installed it with `sudo apt install libbluetooth-dev`. Tried manually adding the `include_directories(SYSTEM /usr/include /usr/include/bluetooth)`, performed CMake `Reset Cache and Reload Project` after every step, nothing worked... Until your answer, after an hour of hair pulling!